# Select all rows from a dataset using the select function except one

Tags: r, dplyr

**The Dataset**

```
autompg = read.table( "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data", quote = "\"", comment.char = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

head(autompg,20)
colnames(autompg) = c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "wt", "acc", "year", "origin", "name")
```

`autompg = autompg %>% select()`

I don't understand what parameter can be used within the select function.

Would `autompg$nrow!=name` work?

Comment: `select` works on columns, it is used for picking subsets of the variables in your dataset. To pick subsets of the samples, i.e. rows, use `filter`, e.g. if you want everything except the Plymouth Duster in your dataset, use `filter(autompg, name != 'plymouth duster')`.

Comment: Btw please edit your dataset code to include breaks after each line of code; in its current form, it won't run if simply cut and pasted.

Comment: You can learn more on [dplyr documentation page](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/)

Answer (score 1):

The `dplyr` basic functions (`select()`, `filter()`, `mutate()`, `arrange()`) are all fairly specific, and generally they don't like it when you try to nest them within one another.

`select()` is for selecting columns, and `filter()` is for filtering rows. If you try to filter within a `select()`, you'll probably get some kind of error.

The parameters you use within `select()` are the columns you want to select. The only other thing you can do within it is rename the columns you are selecting

Here's some code to illustrate what to do:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

# import data
autompg = read.table( "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data", quote = "\"", comment.char = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# change column names
colnames(autompg) = c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "wt", "acc", "year", "origin", "name")

autompg %>% 
  select(name, "miles_per_gallon" = mpg) # selecting only the name and mpg columns, whilst renaming mpg to "miles_per_gallon"
  filter(name != "ford pinto") # filtering out the ford pinto

#                                     name miles_per_gallon
# 1              chevrolet chevelle malibu 18.0
# 2                      buick skylark 320 15.0
# 3                     plymouth satellite 18.0
# 4                          amc rebel sst 16.0
# etc ...
```

Hope this helps!